# Error In suplibOsInit in VirtualBox related to wintab32.dll & secruntime.dll

Tags: virtualbox

Create a empty Linux VM on VirtualBox 5.1.30 at Windows 10, can't even start it, just get the following error pop-up:

[image]

Error In suplibOsInit

The VM process was denied access to vboxdrv because someone have managed to open the process or its main thread with too broad access rights.

Find error opening in VBoxHardening.log:

```
245c.50c: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: error opening 'C:\Windows\system32\wintab32.dll': 0 (NtPath=\??\C:\Windows\system32\wintab32.dll; Input=C:\Windows\system32\wintab32.dll; rcNtGetDll=0x0
245c.50c: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: error opening 'C:\Windows\System32\secruntime.dll': 0 (NtPath=\??\C:\Windows\System32\secruntime.dll; Input=secruntime.dll; rcNtGetDll=0xc0000135
```

There is no wintab32.dll or secruntime.dll in my C:\Windows\System32\ folder. 
I only have Windows Defender installed, no wacom device.

Any hint or suggestion? Thanks in advance.